# Как сделать рекурсивный поиск по файлам только определенного расширения?

Tags: c++, winapi, файловая-система

```
void getFiles(const string& inpath, string outpath)
{
    string mask = inpath + "\\*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;
    hf = FindFirstFile(mask.c_str(), &FindFileData);

    ofstream output;
    output.open(outpath + "\\data.txt", ios_base::app);

    if (hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if (strcmp(FindFileData.cFileName, ".") == 0 ||
                    strcmp(FindFileData.cFileName, "..") == 0) continue;
                getFiles(inpath + "\\" + FindFileData.cFileName, outpath);
            }
            else
                output << inpath << "\\" << FindFileData.cFileName << endl;

        } while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0);
        FindClose(hf);
    }

    output.close();
}
```

Есть такая функция, которая ищет файлы в выбранном каталоге и его подкаталогах, а потом записывает пути к файлам в data.txt. А как мне сделать так, чтобы эта функция искала только файлы с определенным расширением, например, .xml?

Comment: измените маску на `inpath + "\\*.xml"`

Comment: можно парсить строку в поисках нужного расширения.

Comment: @acade, я менял, но тогда программа ничего не ищет и просто заканчивает работу.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, можно, но в случае, когда мне нужно проводить такой поиск по куче расширений, получается много лишней работы. Вот поэтому и ищу какой-то оптимальный вариант.

Comment: @Almagawar всмысле куча работы? Вы что, для каждого расширения функцию собрались писать?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, нет. Просто хотел добавить еще один параметр в функцию - расширение, а потом вызывать ее по необходимости.

Comment: Так одно расширение нужно или несколько одновременно?

Comment: @MBo, за один вызов функции одно расширение.

Comment: И в результате вы хотите десять раз вызвать функцию с десятью расширениями?

Comment: @Almagawar ну так а в чем проблема? Просто в функции напишите парсер - это 2-3 строки кода.

Comment: @MBo, да. Циклом.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, как? Через `strchr`?

Comment: @Almagawar зачем? вы же `string` используете.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, а что использовать мне тогда? Я просто пока только `strchr` нашел.

Comment: @Almagawar я что-то не пойму: вы на си пишите или на с++?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, c++

Comment: @Almagawar ну так в чем проблема сравнить два `string`a между собой?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, извините. Уже не соображаю ничего. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов поиска файлов несколько раз с разными расширениями - неверная концепция. Работа с таблицей файлов (на диске) медленнее, чем обработка строк.

Поэтому соберите все расширения в хэш-таблицу, список, массив или даже в одну строку, просканируйте файлы единожды с универсальной маской `*`. Для каждого найденного файла выделите его расширение и проверьте, есть ли оно в выбранной структуре, хранящей нужные расширения.